# Use serveral HTTP/HTTPs servers in single computer

Tags: http, server

There are many server software like Apache, NGINX, litespeed etc. Also have HTTP server with programming languages like Go, Rust, NodeJS, Bun, Python etc.

All these servers use port 80 or 8080 for HTTP server. There are many HTTP server providers and sometimes need to use few HTTP servers.

Example:

- Python HTTP Server for Machine Learning API
- NodeJS HTTP server for SSR
- Go HTTP server for SDK use cases like DATABASE calling

This is an example. The point is sometimes needing to use few HTTP servers because single server unable to do it. My question is how to handle that situation or how to system design in that situation? (Consider need to use few HTTP servers and use in single computer)

One possible solution I got it is reverse proxy. Install one of server software in Apache, NGINX, litespeed etc. then use reverse proxy rule to other servers. But then performance will be reduce I guess.

Comment: The solution for that is called vhost.

Comment: Reverse proxy is a good solution. The performance overhead is negligible.

Comment: @maio290 you mean make multiple folders for HTTP server by using HTTP software. But it use main server and it transfers to another server. Is it?

Comment: @OsamaNabih when consider high req/sec, it will effect right? When use Rust HTTP server only, can perform much traffic.

Comment: @Ind You can always define some sort of virtual host which would listen to a specific hostname (usually domains and subdomains), you could also use different ports, or like Osama Nabih suggested, a reverse proxy (which would still require the servers to listen on different http ports to avoid conflicts) - so in the end, it's a too broad question to answer and it's also a question for superuser.com. But don't ask it without your specific needs there since generic questions are usually hard to answer.

Comment: @KamilCuk Can not run multiple servers in same machine. It has PORT issue as mention above.

Comment: HTTP Servers are not limited to 80 or 8080, you can use any port not mentioned in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\services`  or (`/etc/services` when on Linux)

Comment: @Luuk thank you for information. You mean use 80 port for web server because browser ask 80 port for web and use other port for APIs etc?

Comment: A webserver running on port 8081 will not complain when you use `http://localhost:8081`

Comment: Possible solutions
1. vHost
2. Proxy
3. Different PORT
Thank you everyone.